# Promotion status

Tags: magento-1.7

Is it important to set a promotion inactive if it is past the end date?
Is there any consequence to inactivating a promotion and then re-activating it?
Or is this simply good house keeping to inactive a promotion past it's end date?

Comment: Have you checked my answer below, describing `Promotional rules` settings ?

Answer (score 0):

`Start Date` and `To Date` are tooo important features/settings for Promotional rules.

Let's say,

- IF Rule is set `Active` and have set `Start Date` and `To Date` both then particular Rule will be applied between these dates (including dates).
- IF Rule is set `Active` and have set `Start Date` ONLY then particular Rule will be applied after this date (including date).
- IF Rule is set `InActive` no matter what dates are set, it will never considered.

So, if you are planning to make particular Rule to be applied in future keep it *InActive* and set it to *Active* when required. Instead deleting and creating again. You can also keep it *Active* and set Start and To dates (of Future), so it'll automatically applied between these dates (including) without activating manually.

SO YES, it's good house keeping to keep Rules inactive instead removing. In other words you can say its a re-usability.

For Catalog Price Rules don't forget to APPLY (Save and Apply button), o/w the changes wont be applied.